# Присвоить значенимой переменной ссылку на другое значение

Tags: c#, ссылки, оператор-присваивания

Допустим мне какая-то внешняя программа `application` имеет свойство `int Status`.

Можно ли получить в свой класс `Foo` ссылку на этот статус, если `application` я получал по ссылке, чтобы `appStatus` и `application.Status` были одним и тем же значением?

```
class Foo
{
    private int appStatus;

    Foo(ref application)
    {
        appStatus = application.Status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, нельзя.

```
class Foo
{
    private Application application;
    private int appStatus { get { return application.Status; } };

    Foo(Application application)
    {
        this.application = application;
    }
}
```

Comment: и в `unsafe` блоке нельзя?